# How to optimise query fetching most recent report for each entry in another table?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I am attempting to optimise a query that displays the last reported movement for a set railroad locomotives. The query currently takes 8-12s to run for a common query to generate a report on a webpage, which outputs around 5,000 rows.

The query involves the following steps:

1. From the table `t1` containing all known locomotives, select those belonging to a specific railroad (or railroads)
2. From the table `t2` containing movement reports, select the most recent report (highest value of `entrynumber`) referencing each entry selected from `t1`
3. From those movement reports selected from `t2`, select only those in the last 30 days
4. Join the selected reports in `t2` to a matching entry in `t3`, if one exists; `t2` will contain a NULL entry if not.

The end result is that for each entry in `t1`, the most recent report in `t2` is output, unless that report is more than 30 days old.

An example query is:

```
SELECT t1.railroad, t1.number, t1.typeid, t2.date, t2.yard, t2.yardmaster, t2.trainsymbol, t3.trainuid 
FROM locodata AS t1 
LEFT JOIN locoreports AS t2 ON t2.locouid = t1.uid
LEFT JOIN tsarreports AS t3 ON t3.entrynumber = t2.tsarReportEntryNum
WHERE t1.railroad IN ('BNSF','BN','CBQ','GN','MILW')
AND t2.entrynumber IN (SELECT MAX(entrynumber) FROM locoreports GROUP BY locouid)
AND t2.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
ORDER BY t1.number ASC
```

The tables involves are as follows:

- `t1`/locodata contains a unique entry for each locomotive, giving some basic information. `t1` contains around 53,000 rows. `t1` has its primary key on (`uid`, `railroad`).
- `t2`/locoreports contains historic location reports for each locomotive, with each location report linked to the corresponding entry in `t1`. Each report has an associated datetime. `t2` contains around 5,700,000 rows. `t2` has its primary key on `entrynumber`, which is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, plus additional keys on `locouid` and `tsarReportEntryNum`.
- `t3`/tsarreports contains train data. Each entry in `t2` *may* link to an entry in `t3`; multiple entries in `t2` can link to the same `t3` entry. `t3` contains around 783,000 rows. `t3` has its primary key on `entrynumber`.

Using `EXPLAIN`, I am very surprised to see that the search on `t2` does not use any key at all, despite one being listed as available. It falls back on a full table scan, which I expect is the slow part!

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t2          | NULL       | ALL    | locouid          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 5980278 |    33.33 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t1          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,railroad | PRIMARY | 8       | fymtraintracker.t2.locouid            |       1 |    32.85 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t3          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 4       | fymtraintracker.t2.tsarReportEntryNum |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | locoreports | NULL       | range  | locouid          | locouid | 8       | NULL                                  |   38646 |   100.00 | Using index for group-by                     |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

So, some queries:

1. Am I missing an obvious key for the tables?
2. Is one of the `WHERE` statements particularly horrible? The subquery in the second `WHERE` statement doesn't seem particularly nice, although the `EXPLAIN` output implies it's not so bad.

Answer (score 1):

So you can re-write this query to address a couple things. The first being because you're filtering on fields from `t2`, you're actually implicitly reducing your results as if you were using an `INNER JOIN` as opposed to a `LEFT JOIN` from `t1`, with the same predicate. There are some minute reasons why `INNER JOINS` are more performant than `OUTER JOINS` as well, so might as well use an `INNER JOIN` here like so:

```
SELECT t1.railroad, t1.number, t1.typeid, t2.date, t2.yard, t2.yardmaster, t2.trainsymbol, t3.trainuid 
FROM locodata AS t1 
INNER JOIN locoreports AS t2 ON t2.locouid = t1.uid
LEFT JOIN tsarreports AS t3 ON t3.entrynumber = t2.tsarReportEntryNum
WHERE t1.railroad IN ('BNSF','BN','CBQ','GN','MILW')
AND t2.entrynumber IN (SELECT MAX(entrynumber) FROM locoreports GROUP BY locouid)
AND t2.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
ORDER BY t1.number ASC
```

Now that's definitely not going to fix all your performance problems, just something conceptually important to be aware of. Next thing I would suggest is try to avoid using subqueries in predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses) as while not inherently always bad, generally can lead to suboptimal queries to be written as opposed to a more naturally relational equivalent. For example, in this case `locoreports` is by far your largest table (almost 6 million rows) and yet your query has to operate and reduce the data on it twice, when instead we can smartly get the rows with the latest `entrynumber` first and then join to only those rows like so:

```
SELECT t1.railroad, t1.number, t1.typeid, t2.date, t2.yard, t2.yardmaster, t2.trainsymbol, t3.trainuid 
FROM locodata AS t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT date, yard, yardmaster, trainsymbol, locouid, tsarReportEntryNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY locouid ORDER BY entrynumber DESC) AS SortId
    FROM locoreports AS t2 
    WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
) AS t2
ON t2.locouid = t1.uid
AND t2.SortId = 1
LEFT JOIN tsarreports AS t3 ON t3.entrynumber = t2.tsarReportEntryNum
WHERE t1.railroad IN ('BNSF','BN','CBQ','GN','MILW')
ORDER BY t1.number ASC
```

The above leverages the [**`ROW_NUMBER()` window function**](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) which is awesomely helpful for getting the max / min / top N rows of a grouping (`PARTITION`) however you want to order it, and generally is pretty efficient at doing so. `ROW_NUMBER()` will generate a unique ID for each row within the `PARTITION` (grouping) in the order you specify, this case on `entrynumber` descending. Then we can subsequently filter on only the first (latest) `entrynumber` in the `JOIN` predicates to the subquery with `AND t2.SortId = 1`. (Side note, you can change the 1 to any number and that's the N number of latest rows by `t2.entrynumber` descending you'd get back, but in your specific example you only want the very latest.)

This allowed us to remove the subquery on `locoreports` from your `WHERE` clause, and effectively we only need to process and reduce the data from `locoreports` once. I also moved up the filter on the `date` into the subquery as well. I wrote it in a subquery in the above example, though I normally like to refactor that stuff into a CTE just for readability, but I'm unsure of your MySQL version which may or may not support CTEs. Also, there may be other potential performance improvements you can try as well, but the above two things are what jumped out at me.